# Running Jupyter program using shell script

Tags: python, shell, jenkins, jupyter

I am trying to run my Jupyter program using shell script. However I am unsure of how to do so. I want to run my program on Jenkins, which is a platform that will require my code to be run in shell script in order to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be covered in the [docs](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html).  Example:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute mynotebook.ipynb
```